# Reflecting superclass's value type arguments in Scala, without TypeTag

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

In Java, while type arguments are erased in runtime, it is possible to find the actual type arguments passed to a superclass:

```java
class Derived extends Base<String> {
  // ...
}

ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType)Derived.class.getGenericSuperclass();
Type[] args = type.getActualTypeArguments(); // gives {String.class}
```

While I can use the same Java reflection to Scala class, It does not catch Scala's value types:

```scala
class Base[T]
class Derived extends Base[Int]

classOf[Derived]
  .getGenericSuperclass
  .asInstanceOf[ParameterizedType]
  .getActualTypeArguments // gives {Object.class}, not {int.class}
```

Is it possible to determine the value type used when extending from a generic superclass? I am loading classes from a jar file so it'd be best to achieve this only using a `java.lang.Class` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java reflection you won't be able to obtain `Int` and other `AnyVal` types because they are handled specially by the compiler and if they are used generically, they will be represented by `Object`. However, you can use Scala reflection, and it is wholly possible to go from Java reflection to Scala reflection. Here's how:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class Base[T]

class Derived extends Base[Int]

object Main extends App {
  val rm = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)  // whatever class loader you're using

  val derivedSym = rm.staticClass(classOf[Derived].getName)
  val baseSym = rm.staticClass(classOf[Base[_]].getName)
  val TypeRef(_, _, params) = derivedSym.typeSignature.baseType(baseSym)
  println(s"$derivedSym extends $baseSym[${params.mkString(", ")}]")
}
```

Unfortunately, unless you know exactly what you are searching for, you will have hard time finding proper documentation. I have found the answer on [scala-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/CTmifUgnQ4c). Scala reflection is still experimental and, AFAIK, it will probably be superseded by a better one in future Scala versions.